# Init an object in MainActivity then access it globally

Tags: java, android

I want to create an object in my MainActivity but I want to access it globally ,So Let's say I have this class

```
public class User {

private String description;
private String display_name;
private String email;
private String followers;
private String following;
private String posts;
private String profile_photo;
private String user_id;
private String username;

public User(){}


public User(String description, String display_name, String email, String followers, String following, String posts, String profile_photo, String user_id, String username) {
    this.description = description;
    this.display_name = display_name;
    this.email = email;
    this.followers = followers;
    this.following = following;
    this.posts = posts;
    this.profile_photo = profile_photo;
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.username = username;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getDisplay_name() {
    return display_name;
}

public void setDisplay_name(String display_name) {
    this.display_name = display_name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getFollowers() {
    return followers;
}

public void setFollowers(String followers) {
    this.followers = followers;
}

public String getFollowing() {
    return following;
}

public void setFollowing(String following) {
    this.following = following;
}

public String getPosts() {
    return posts;
}

public void setPosts(String posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
}

public String getProfile_photo() {
    return profile_photo;
}

public void setProfile_photo(String profile_photo) {
    this.profile_photo = profile_photo;
}

public String getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", display_name='" + display_name + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", followers='" + followers + '\'' +
            ", following='" + following + '\'' +
            ", posts='" + posts + '\'' +
            ", profile_photo='" + profile_photo + '\'' +
            ", user_id='" + user_id + '\'' +


               ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And The method to fill all parameters is in MainActivity

```
public static User currentUser;

private void setupFirebase() {


    Log.e(TAG, "setupFirebase: Setting up firebase");

    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: Retrieving data.....");
            FirebaseMethods firebaseMethods = new FirebaseMethods(mContext);
            currentUser = new User();
            currentUser = firebaseMethods.getUserSettings(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Now I have multiple Activities and fragments how can I access this  `currentUser` object elsewhere, I know I can use something like this `currentUser = MainActivity.currentUser;` but is there any better/more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: you can use ViewModel and Parcelable. With a viewModel, your user will be seen by the actual activity and all its child fragments. When switching to an other activity, you can put the user into the intent, but the class User has to implement Parcelable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good idea to do some operations with data in Activity.
I advise you to look at: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/08/google-releases-source-for-google-io.html

There are several options:

1. Load data into ViewModel and use single ViewModel for several Fragments.
2. Save your data somewhere (for example database) and load for each screen from there ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room))
3. Use Rx for sharing downloaded data for several subscribers somewhere in your repository.
4. Serialize object using Gson or Parcelable and send via intent.

In my opinion, the third variant is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following procedure. You can create global variable keep remain values around the life cycle of the application regardless which activity running.

**1. Extend the base Application class**

Extend the base `android.app.Application` class and add member variables like so:

```
    public class myUser extends Application {

    private String description;
    ...

    public String getDescription() {
         return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
         this.description = description;
    }

    ...

   }
```

**2. Declare it in Manifest:**

In your android `manifest` you must declare the class implementing `android.app.Application` (add the `android:name=".myUser"` attribute to the existing application tag):

```
<application 
  android:name=".myUser" 
  android:icon="@drawable/my_icon" 
  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

**3. Set/Get variables in activities**

In your activities and fragments you can `get` and `set` the variable like so:

```
// initialise your user variable
// set description variable
((myUser) this.getApplication()).setDescription("your description");

// get description variable
String s = ((myUser) this.getApplication()).getDescription();
```

Hope it will be help you.